# conditionally enable button with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
<div class="error-message"></div>

 <form id="satisfaction" onsubmit="return validateInput()">
  <input type="radio" name="satisfied"  value="yes" required /> Satisfied
 <input type="checkbox" name="donate" /> Donate<br />
<input type="radio"  name="satisfied" value="no" required /> Not satisfied
    <input type="text" name="reason" /> Reason<br />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  <script>
```

jQuery:

```
$('input[name="donate"]').attr('disabled', 'true');

$(document).ready(function () {
$('input[name="satisfied"]').click(function(){

  $('input[name="donate"]').removeAttr("disabled");

});});
```

How can I  write a code in jQuery that lets the user check the "donate" button if and only if the "satisfied" button is checked?

Comment: Add what have you tried till now to your question!

Comment: Use [`$.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `$.attr`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this

```
$('input[name="donate"]').attr('disabled', true);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="satisfied"]').on('change', function() {
    if ($('input[name="satisfied"]:checked').val() == 'yes')
      $('input[name="donate"]').removeAttr("disabled");
    else
      $('input[name="donate"]').attr('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6syhqzf9/

Comment: I believe the best practice is to use `.prop` for enabling/disabling inputs

Answer (score 0):

Start with the donate input disabled

```
<input type="radio" name="satisfied"  value="yes" required /> Satisfied
<input type="checkbox" name="donate" disabled="disabled"/> Donate<br />
<input type="radio"  name="satisfied" value="no" required /> Not satisfied
```

Using the `change` event, you can enable the box if the user selects 'satisfied', otherwise disable it.

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
    $('input[name="satisfied"]').on('change', function(){
        var val = $('input[name="satisfied"]:checked').val(); //either 'yes' or 'no'
        var $donate = $('input[name="donate"]');  //this is the donate input
        if(val == 'yes')
            $donate.prop('disabled', false);
        else
            $donate.prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```